# How to drop last not NaN value in Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, nan

| a1 | a2 | a3 | Last_Not_NaN_Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NaN | NaN | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | NaN | 0 |
| NaN | 5 | NaN | 5 |

I've managed so far to get last not NaN value in the row this way:

```
data.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]
```

But, I also need to replace that value with NaN (drop it from the DataFrame)

Comment: what do you want to replace instead of NaN value

Answer (score 1):

Create a boolean mask to identify non-nan values, then calculate `cumsum` along `axis=1` then `mask` the values in original dataframe where `cumsum` is maximum

```
m = df.notna()
s = m.cumsum(1)
df.mask(s.eq(s.max(1), axis=0))
```

---

```
    a1  a2  a3
0  NaN NaN NaN
1  0.0 NaN NaN
2  NaN NaN NaN
```

PS: There is no need to create an intermediate column `Last_Not_NaN_Value`

Answer (score 1):

one way is to use last_valid_index on each row:

```
df = df[['a1', 'a2', 'a3']] #just in case
for i, r in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[i, r.last_valid_index()] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

seq = (
    df    # set index and column values by their ordinal numbers
    .set_axis(range(df.shape[0]), axis=0)
    .set_axis(range(df.shape[1]), axis=1)
    .agg(pd.DataFrame.last_valid_index, 1)
)
df.values[seq.index, seq] = pd.NA
```

Here

- `df` is a given data frame;
- `seq` - associate rows with a corresponding last valid column number;
- `df.values` is a `numpy.array` and it's a view to the values of `df`
- `values[seq.index, seq]` is [Integer array indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing), which allows selection of arbitrary items in `df` (it's a view to the original data, so we can use assigning to change those values).